# Copy file to usr/shar/lib folder in amazon aws ec2

Tags: linux

How can i copy any file to "usr/share/tomcat6/lib" folder?
It displays access denied on trying to copy or move.
Also, it doesn't allows me to change the file permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sudo` to do that

```
sudo cp filename /usr/share/tomcat6/lib
```

To change file permission, use `chmod` with `sudo`

```
 sudo chmod 777 filename
```